# C++ Template style code

Tags: c++, templates

What does * mean in the following template style c++ code:
`class_name<T, S>* obj_name;`

The template class is defined as follows in a .h file:

```
template <typename T,int S>
class class_name {
    public:
    //function definitions follow
```

Comment: Same thing it means in any other context immediately following a type : pointer-to, in this case pointer to an instance (or derivation) of `class_name<T,S>`

Comment: It's a pointer to an object...

Comment: @WhozCraig: Why do you write an answer in a comment?

Answer (score 3):

`class_name` is the name of the templated class, `*` means pointer to. So `obj_name` is a pointer to an instance of `class_name` parametrized with `T, S` (with T, S likely being dependent on outer code that is also parametrized thus).

Answer (score 1):

For any type `Type`, the following code declares and defines a pointer-to-`Type` called `t`:

```
Type* t;
```

In your example, `Type` happens to be the class `class_name<T, S>`, which is an instance of the class template `class_name`.

```
class_name<T, S>* obj_name;
```

What else would it be?